# Conditionally Assign Value to Dask Dataframe using Apply

Tags: dask

I am trying to iterate through a Dask dataframe and compare the values in one of its columns to a  column in another Dask dataframe with the same name. If the columns match I would like to update the value is the target Dask dataframe. The code below runs, but the values are not updated to '1' where I expected, or anywhere. I am  new to Dask and suspect I am missing some crucial step or am not understanding the framework.

```
def populateSymptomsDDF(row):
    for vac in row['vac_codes']:
        if vac in symptoms_ddf.columns:
            symptoms_ddf[vac] = symptoms_ddf[vac].where(symptoms_ddf['dog'] == row['dog'], 1)


with ProgressBar():
    x = vac_ddf.apply(lambda x: populateSymptomsDDF(x), meta=('int64'), axis=1)
    x.compute(scheduler='processes') 
    symptoms_ddf.compute()
```

Head of icd_ddf:

```
dog vac_codes
0   1   [G35, E11.40, R53.1, Z79.899, I87.2]
1   2   [G35, R53.83, G47.00]
2   3   [G35, G95.9, R53.83, F41.9]
3   4   [G35, N53.9, E55.9, Z74.09]
4   5   [G35, M51.26, R53.1, M47.816, R25.2, G82.50, R...
```

Head of symptoms_ddf (before running code):

```
dog W19 W10 W05.0   V00.811 R53.83  R53.8   R53.1   R47.9   R47.89  ... G81.12  G81.11  G81.10  G50.0   G31.84  F52.8   F52.31  F52.22  F52.0   F03
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Thank you for any insights you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

Dask dataframes don't have the same in-place behavior as pandas.  Generally every operation should be a bulk parallel operation.  Otherwise there isn't much reason to use Dask.

Also, iterating through dataframes will generally be quite slow.  This is also true with Pandas.

Fortunately, I think that you're maybe just looking for a join or merge operation.  I would encourage you to look up the documentation for Pandas merge

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html